# Modifying the default bashrc alert command

Tags: alias, bashrc

I was scrolling through my bashrc *(bored)* and I got interested in the **alert** command that is concatenated in there by default. It's practical and everything, but it requires you to type `; alert` at the end of every comand you want to be notified about.

Is there a smart way of turning this alias into something like a universal command option?

**Examples:**

```
sudo apt update -a 
cp <someBigFile> <someOtherPlace> -a
```

etc. (**e**nd of **t**hinking **c**apacity :)

I know that I can't necessarily use "-a", as it might be an existing option for some commmands, it's just an example I put up there to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways how to achieve it. But TBH I'm using the same approach as You described. `command; alert`.

**1. create function which calls Your command You want to be notified after it finishes.**

```
function alert(){
        $@
        echo -en "\a"
}
```

So running `alert sudo apt-update` will ring a bell after it finishes.

**2. function to set/unset alerting and call it with PROMPT_COMMAND**

```
function alert(){
        case $1 in
                "")
                        [[ -n $alert ]] && echo -en "\a";;
                set)
                        export alert=true;;
                unset)
                        unset alert;;
        esac
}

# add function alert to your PROMPT_COMMAND
PROMPT_COMMAND='alert'
```

then You can enable alerts:

```
alert set
command1
command2
alert unset
```

**2b. both combined**

```
function alert(){
        case $1 in
                "")
                        [[ -n $alert ]] && echo -en "\a";;
                set)
                        export alert=true;;
                unset)
                        unset alert;;
                *)
                        $@
                        echo -en "\a";;
        esac
}

# add function alert to your PROMPT_COMMAND
PROMPT_COMMAND='alert'
```

both ways described above:
`alert sudo apt update`
or

```
alert set
command1
command2
aler unset
```

Comment: Nice! I like both ideas :D Those are getting added to my bashrc. Thx for the help.

If I understand correctly you can make a sort of concatenation of both solutions right?

Comment: what do you mean with  "make a sort of concatenation"?

Comment: I could add version one as an else clause to option two... So basically put "set" or "unset" or "<other command>" as cases. Or am I completely off here and missing omething?

Comment: yes, sure add  another case matching everything else.